# CSS - Fix issues on zooming the cards layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zooming

I have eight cards on my web page along with a heading. My layout is breaking completely on zooming in and out.

You can see it here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/st.anthony/#faculty_section

I have tried to change the height of the card to em units to hold together the image and text inside it, but it still completely breaks. How can I solve this issue?

PS: I have used bootstrap to achieve the grid layout

HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Distinguished Faculty Members</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card extra-left-margin">
                <img src="images/mrs_m_sinha_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs M Sinha</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Biology</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card">
                <img src="images/mrs_francis_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs M Francis</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Physics</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card">
                <img src="images/mrs_khalkho_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs A Khalkho</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Hindi</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card">
                <img src="images/mrs_verma_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs P Verma</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Hindi</h6>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card extra-left-margin-less-top">
                <img src="images/mrs_kumar_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs A Kumar</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of English</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card less-top-margin">
                <img src="images/mrs_kenwar_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs A Kenwar</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Geography <br> (Now Retired)</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card less-top-margin">
                <img src="images/mrs_srivastav_optimised.png" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs Shrivastav</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Hindi</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 card less-top-margin">
                <img src="images/the_principal.jpg" alt="faculty">
                <h4>Mrs K Franklin</h4>
                <h6>Faculty of Everything <br> (Now Retired)</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16em;
    margin: 3% 3% 2% 3%;
    position: relative;
    width: 13%;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.less-top-margin {
    margin: 1% 3% 2% 3%;

}

.extra-left-margin {
    margin: 3% 3% 2% 14%;
}

.extra-left-margin-less-top {
    margin: 1% 3% 2% 14%;
}


.section-heading {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4f2500;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono",monospace;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.card img {
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 8% auto 25% auto;
}

.card h4 {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono",sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
}

.card h6 {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.68em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
    line-height:1.5 ;
}
```

Link to the repository: https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/st.anthony

Comment: When you say 'zooming up and down', are you talking about using the native 'Zoom In' & 'Zoom Out' features for the browser?

Comment: yes, i will edit it with the proper terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change css

```
.card {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* height: 16em; */  **<---- REMOVE** 
    margin: 3% 3% 2% 3%;
    position: relative;
    width: 13%;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    padding: 10px;  <----- ADD
}
```

in media query section

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
.card img {
    width: 75%;
    /* margin: 8% auto 20% auto; */  **<---- REMOVE** 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 920px)
.card img {
    width: 75%;
    /* margin: 8% auto 35% auto; */ **<---- REMOVE** 
}
```

Comment: I will need to adjust margins, but other than that, it was perfect. Thank you!